# How assigning a value to Variable is working in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssrs, reporting

Recently started learning Reporting Services using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Reporting Services, [Fifth Edition](https://www.mhprofessional.com/9781259641503-usa-microsoft-sql-server-2016-reporting-services-fifth-edition-group), Brian Larson.
I am creating this one report which uses UNION to create a dataset, FuelType, that will be used for assigning values to a dropdown list.

```
SELECT 'All' AS Fueltype, '_All' AS SortField
UNION
SELECT Description, Description FROM Propulsion ORDER BY SortField
```

Now there exists another dataset that will help generate the chart for me and there.

```
SELECT Propulsion.Description AS Fueltype, FuelPrice.PriceStartDate, FuelPrice.Price    
FROM  FuelPrice 
INNER JOIN Propulsion ON FuelPrice.PropulsionID = Propulsion.PropulsionID
WHERE        (YEAR(FuelPrice.PriceStartDate) = @year) AND  (Propulsion.Description = @PropulsionType) 
OR  (YEAR(FuelPrice.PriceStartDate) = @year) AND (@PropulsionType = 'All')
ORDER BY Fueltype, FuelPrice.PriceStartDate
```

I do not understand, how by using "@PropulsionType = 'All'" I am able to pass in all available values to the parameter.

[image]

For someone who has the book, this is under Chapter 6 :Fuel Price Chart, Version 2

Comment: Pages from the book are [viewable on amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-Server-Reporting-Services-Fifth/dp/1259641503). Chapter 6 starts on p. 267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS isn't doing anything special.  It's actually the query that's making the distinction to either pull all fuel types or just the one specified, though I suspect the book has a typo because it looks to be missing an extra pair of parenthesis.  The real magic is supposed to be happening in the predicate, here:

```
WHERE  (YEAR(FuelPrice.PriceStartDate) = @year) AND (Propulsion.Description = @PropulsionType) 
   OR  (YEAR(FuelPrice.PriceStartDate) = @year) AND (@PropulsionType = 'All')
```

This really should be written in one of the two following ways:

```
WHERE  ((YEAR(FuelPrice.PriceStartDate) = @year) AND (Propulsion.Description = @PropulsionType))
   OR  ((YEAR(FuelPrice.PriceStartDate) = @year) AND (@PropulsionType = 'All'))
```

Or, another way:

```
WHERE (YEAR(FuelPrice.PriceStartDate) = @year) 
 AND  ((Propulsion.Description = @PropulsionType) 
        OR  (@PropulsionType = 'All'))
```

Basically what this is doing is in the event  your report is passed the `'All'` parameter, don't filter on `Propulsion.Description`.  If a parameter is passed that is not `'All'`, you want to filter on that specific value.  Taking SSRS out of it, you can see the working example via this [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cfb1efe31e56ae406f29403723045eb5) link.

Comment: Thank you , I was in a tunnel vision and couldn't grasp the usage. I now understand that using the string as a filter that is not present in the column will basically mean, "filter on nothing"!

P.S.: The typo is not in the book, but at my end, while typing out the query while posting the question I made that mistake.